# Enderman spawn rates

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I built a Enderman farm in the second dimension of the end (end city) and now I wonder if the Enderman from the main End affect the spawn rates in the second dimension? Because my farm isn't that efficient like it should be.

I flooded the whole second dimension with water, even at the sides of the island I flooded ever single block Enderman could spawn of with water so the problem most be something else. I also built the farm as low as possible without any lighting.

I know spawn rates at the xbox360 version are low but at my farm there are just spawning around 16 Enderman and that it stops.

So guys, any ideas how to improve my spawn rates? Is there an affect from the main End?

Comment: If the chunks for the "main end" are not loaded, then no, there is no effect. Given that end islands are a minimum of 10,000 blocks (I think?) from the "main end", those chunks are not loaded, and not effecting your spawn rates. But other islands in the chunks around your spawner will.  Make sure you've spawn-proofed *all of them*, not just a couple. There may be some you missed. Also set up your speaker to kill the endermen ASAP, so that you don't hit the mob cap, and prevent more endermen from spawning.